# android : fetal exception issue : main

Tags: android, zooming, drag

I copied this code from a book and tried to run that , basically it draw a rectangle in the screen and then try to apply zoom and drag to it . but unfortunately it's not working and give me fetal error . what's the problem?

here is the code :

```
public class DrawStuffActivity extends Activity implements
    OnTouchListener {

      MyView myView;
      int numberOfFingers = 0;
      float oldX[] = new float[2], oldY[] = new float[2];
      Rect rectangle = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
      DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myView = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(myView);
        myView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().
          getMetrics(metrics);
      }
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          numberOfFingers = 1;
          oldX[0] = event.getX(0);
          oldY[0] = event.getY(0);
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
          numberOfFingers = 2;
          oldX[1] = event.getX(1);
          oldY[1] = event.getY(1);
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          handleMove(event);
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          numberOfFingers--;
          break;
        }
        view.invalidate();
        return true;
      }
    float newX[] = new float[2], newY[] = new float[2];
    int xChange[] = new int[2], yChange[] = new int[2];
    int diffX, diffY;
    int newLeft = rectangle.left, newTop = rectangle.top,
        newRight = rectangle.right,
        newBottom = rectangle.bottom;
    void handleMove(MotionEvent event) {
      newX[0] = Math.round(event.getX(0));
      newY[0] = Math.round(event.getY(0));
      xChange[0] = Math.round(newX[0] - oldX[0]);
      yChange[0] = Math.round(newY[0] - oldY[0]);
      oldX[0] = newX[0];
      oldY[0] = newY[0];
      switch (numberOfFingers) {
      case 1:

          newLeft = rectangle.left + xChange[0];
            newTop = rectangle.top + yChange[0];
            newRight = rectangle.right + xChange[0];
            newBottom = rectangle.bottom + yChange[0];
            if (newLeft < 0 || newRight > metrics.widthPixels) {
              newLeft = rectangle.left;
              newRight = rectangle.right;
            }
            if (newTop < 0 || newBottom > metrics.heightPixels) {
              newTop = rectangle.top;
              newBottom = rectangle.bottom;
            }
            rectangle =
                new Rect(newLeft, newTop, newRight, newBottom);
            break;
          case 2:
            newX[1] = Math.round(event.getX(1));
            newY[1] = Math.round(event.getY(1));
            diffX =
                Math.abs(Math.round(newX[1] - newX[0]))
                    - Math.abs(Math.round(oldX[1] - oldX[0]));
            diffY =
                Math.abs(Math.round(newY[1] - newY[0]))
                    - Math.abs(Math.round(oldY[1] - oldY[0]));
            oldX[1] = newX[1];
            oldY[1] = newY[1];
            newLeft = rectangle.left - diffX / 2;
            newTop = rectangle.top - diffY / 2;
            newRight = rectangle.right + diffX / 2;
            newBottom = rectangle.bottom + diffY / 2;
            rectangle =
                new Rect(newLeft, newTop, newRight, newBottom);
            break;
          }

    }

    // The handleMove method is in Listing 3-6.
      class MyView extends View {
        Paint whitePaint = new Paint();
        MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            whitePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
          }
          @Override
          public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawRect(rectangle, whitePaint);
          }
        }
      }
```

and here is the error :

```
 05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.allmycode.draw/com.allmycode.draw.DrawstaffActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.allmycode.draw.DrawstaffActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.allmycode.draw-1.apk]
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.allmycode.draw.DrawstaffActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.allmycode.draw-1.apk]
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
05-03 08:40:57.597: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  ... 11 more
```

the manifest.xml seems ok :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.allmycode.draw"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DrawstaffActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what is the rest of the logcat output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me. Probably something with your project setup.
I just created a new project and copied your code into it.
A white square that can be moved around.

[edit]
Now when you did post the rest of the logcat its easier to see what happened.
The classnotfound error comes from time to time. I learned that the easiest way to resolv it, is to create a new project, and move the code to the new project.

[edit again]

Your manifest: .DrawstaffActivity
Your code:      DrawStuffActivity

Comment: Your manifest: .DrawstaffActivity Your code: DrawStuffActivity => It will work, the manifest can work with . or package before activity name. .DrawstaffActivity  justmean the current package name.

Comment: I mean the spelling is different. staff/Stuff. Logcat: ClassNotFoundException: com.allmycode.draw.DrawstaffActivity Of course it does not work, because there is no class with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Register your Activity class `DrawStuffActivity` in `AndroidManifest` file.